# Simple block cipher

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, xor

I came up with this concept, which I thought would be pretty secure.

So the idea is this, you have a message $M$, which you split up in blocks of each 256 bits. You generate a random *(pseudo-random of course)* key of $256$ bits. You XOR the first block of $M$ with this key, which is also the input key for the second block, and so on. Would this be a secure scheme? My theory is that since XOR has the property that if you were given

$Z = X \oplus Y$

You can't extract $X$ nor $Y$ from $Z$

So you would have to guess every key in the 256 bit keyspace and go through this "*encryption*" process and see if you get some logical output.

So, would this be safe?

Comment: @kelalaka what do you mean?

Comment: This is [auto key cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autokey_cipher).. Right?

Comment: I never heard of an autokey cipher, but would the exact process I described be safe? For example encrypting an executable or some certificate

Comment: Any encryption scheme which works (in the sense of allowing decryption with the key), and uses XOR as the only crypto primitive, is insecure. Hint: Ask yourself how you would recognize a message consisting of two blocks of zeros, from one with two blocks of English text, by looking at the ciphertext. This is a break. It goes worse: exploiting redundancy in the plaintext (such as: it contains common works) for key recovery from ciphertext only is an ages-old practice.

Comment: Yes, it's a variant of Vigenere.

Comment: Hey, I've not seen this construction since University, which was embarrassingly long ago (and was just CS, not crypto). I can remember some kind of sliding window cryptanalysis on it. It wasn't secure.

Comment: You are unclear about the actual encryption process - my understanding is that this would have the same weakness as AES-ECB. Is the following correct? $C_i = M_i \oplus K_i$? Also @fgrieu don't forget the one time pad.

Comment: @Legorooj: yes, I forgot to explictly mention the condition _and allow reuse of key_. To my defense, that condition is part of the modern definition of a cipher (hence the OTP is not a cipher), and applies to the question's encryption scheme.

Comment: @fgrieu good point. But then what is OTP classed as then?

Comment: @Legorooj: I'd say the OTP is an encryption scheme, but not a cipher. That's a matter of convention.

Answer (score 6):

This is a slight variation of the [autokey cipher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autokey_cipher), which was invented by Vigenere, and can be seen as another variant of the Vigenere cipher. The major differences are: It used a different alphabet, the keysize is fixed, and you reuse the ciphertext instead of the key or plaintext.

Therefore, even without looking at the the details, it is fairly obvious that frequency analysis will break it.

Looking closer:

- if you look at a single block only, it looks like you have an OTP (which would be secure, if you use a truly random and uniform key).
- However, if we XOR two consecutive blocks $c_{i-1}\oplus c_{i}$, we immediately get the plaintext $m_i$ of that block - because that is just your construction.

So effectively, you only encrypt the first block at all, and anyone can just "decrypt" the other blocks, since the following key is just the previous ciphertext. Of course this has no security at all, unless you limit messages to one block. And then it is just either OTP (if the key is truly random and uniform) or a stream cipher (if the key is generated somehow).